# How to prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \prod_{k=1}^n b_k = l>0$ then, for any $0<c_k<b_k$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-c_k) < l$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

> How to prove that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \prod_{k=1}^n b_k = l>0$$ then for any $0<c_k<b_k$ $$ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-c_k) < l \ \ \ \ \ ?$$

My professor mentioned this to me today but didn't prove it. I agree with him that it is intuitive, but since we're dealing with a limit we "could" (*) have $c_k$ converge to $0$ so fast that the statement doesn't hold, so I'm looking for a proof, which I really cannot think of, I guess I'd need more familiarity with infinite products.

(*) In fact the statement is supported by numerical evidence even in that sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $\displaystyle u_n=a_n\prod_{k=1}^n b_k$, $\displaystyle v_n=a_n\prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-c_k)$
You have for $n\geq 2$:

$$\frac{v_n}{u_n}=\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{c_k}{b_k})=(1-\frac{c_1}{b_1})\prod_{k=2}^n (1-\frac{c_k}{b_k})\leq (1-\frac{c_1}{b_1})$$

Comment: $\lim v_n = \lim u_n$ implies $\lim \frac{v_n}{u_n}=1$, which is a contradiction because the limiting ratio is at most $1-\frac{c_1}{b_1}$, and thus $\lim v_n < \lim u_n$. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Could you confirm that the statement does not hold if $c_k$ is replaced by $c_n$? For example, the argument using $c_1$ doesn't work under this condition.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I did not connect to MSE these last days. For your question, take $a_n=1$, $b_n=1$, $c_n=1/2^n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then $u_n=1\to 1$, and  (with $c_k$ replaced by $c_n$) $v_{n}=(1-1/2^n)^n \to 1$ also.

Comment: No worries, thanks again!